# How to check All Checkboxes by clicking a checkbox or it's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox which will call jquery function given below to check all checkboxes in the page:

```
//to check all checkbox
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

But I also wanted to call the same jquery function when I click "Select All" text in the following,  but its not working:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> 
<a id="checkAll" onclick="document.getElementById('checkAll').checked=true" style="cursor:pointer"> Select All </a>
```

Comment: You don't need a click-handler to update the `checked` property of a check-box, it's automatic. Also, that check-box can never be unchecked by the user (unless you've got another script running that does that, which is doubly redundant).

Comment: @DavidThomas notice that the handler is changing the value of all checkboxes in the page, not only the one he clicked on. You are correct about the re-chekcing (or unchecking) of the checkboxes, the user indeed could never flip it's value otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated :***

`ID` cannot be assign Twice In a Document ! `ID` is a `Unique` `Key` for Select an element, you have to Use `class` if you want to select two element at once!

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> 
<a class="checkAll" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('checkAll')[0].checked=true" style="cursor:pointer"> Select All </a>
```

Or the **Another Way** to Solve your Problem Is to use `Label` tag and wrap your `input:checkbox` into it ,Like

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> 
Select All
</label>
```

Comment: i like the second one

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the duplicate `id` and inline js from the `<a>`, You can use jQuery like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#checkAll, #checkAll + a").click(function(){
    var checked =  $("#checkAll").prop('checked');
    if(this.id=="checkAll")
      $(":checkbox").prop('checked', checked );
    else
      $(":checkbox").prop('checked', !checked );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put two elements with the same id in the same page. Ids are suppossed to be unique.

Besides, you're making a strange mix of jQuery code and inline event handlers. Try this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" class="checkAll"/> 
    <a class="checkAll" style="cursor:pointer"> Select All </a>
```

javascript:

```
//to check all checkbox
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkAll").click(function () {
        var checkbox = $('#checkAll');
        if (this.id !== 'checkAll') checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        var checked = checkbox.prop('checked');
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it is illegal to give two different elements the same ID. Provide the  tag with a different ID than the input tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> 
<a id="btnCheckAll" onclick="document.getElementById('checkAll').checked=true" style="cursor:pointer"> Select All </a>
```

And then you can change the jQuery code into something like this:

```
//to check all checkbox
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkAll #btnCheckAll").click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

By the way - it doesn't seem like this code is intend to always check all Checkboxes, but rather flips their value.